# How can i add text to the text area without replacing the old text

Tags: php

**I want to add text to an text area. BUT not to replace it
  The text should look like that**

Hello 
 and when i click the button -> Hello John

Thats my code now. When i write something and want to add it to the text area than it replaces it
but i want that it adds to it.
Like that : (https://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/add-text.html) | BUT with php and 
like echo or print how i did that.

```php
<?php
    $commentFile = fopen("comments.txt", "a");
    $comments = $_POST['comments'].PHP_EOL;

    fwrite($commentFile, $comments);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
<h5>     
    <textarea readonly id="comment" style="font-family: sans-serif; color: black" >                           
        <?php echo "$comments"; ?>
    </textarea>
</h5>
<div>         
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label> Write a comment</label>
        <textarea id="writec" name="comments" input type="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use _javascript_ for this?

Comment: It should be like a comment box. I want to save the text that a user writes in a .txt file. I dont know how i should do that with javascript

Comment: Javascript would be much better suited for this kind of operation. The article you linked actually explains how to do it in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with Javascript

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   <?php
    $commentFile = fopen("comments.txt", "a");
    $comments = $_POST['comments'].PHP_EOL;

    fwrite($commentFile, $comments);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
<h5>     
    <input readonly id="comment" style="font-family: sans-serif; color: black" value="<?php echo "$comments"; ?>">                           


</h5>
<div>         
    <form action="#">
        <label> Write a comment</label>
        <input id="writec" name="comments" type="text">
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-secondary' name="button" onClick="addtext();">
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addtext() {

    var txt = (document.getElementById("comment").value)+(document.getElementById("writec").value);
    //alert(txt);
    document.getElementById("comment").value=txt;
}
    </script>
```